# Merge several .csv into one csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, concatenation

Good evening,

So I have a huge amount of .csvs which I either want to change in one giant csv before reading it with pandas, or directly creating a df with all the .csvs in it. The .csvs all have two columns "timestamp" and "holdings". Now I want to merge them on the "timestamp"-column if they match with each other and create a new column for each "holdings"-column. So far I produced this:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("C/USer....")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
        for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv')]
```

The output is a list with dfs. How do I merge them on "timestamp" column now? I tried to `concate` and `merge` already, but it always puts them in a single column.

Comment: do all files have the same columns? can you post `print(*dfs[:2], sep='\n\n')`?

Comment: yes, they unfortunately have the same column, with the same name...  Output looks like this;                     users_holding
timestamp                         
2018-05-02 04:54:46            158
2018-05-02 06:39:57            158
2018-05-03 00:36:38            158
2018-05-03 06:35:01            158
2018-05-03 06:50:00            158
                           ...

Comment: you can edit your questions to include the dfs, it will help you get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an outer join between the dataframes. Since the pandas `merge` function only operates between two dataframes, we need to loop over each dataframe and merge them individually. We can use the `reduce` iterator from `functools` to do this cleanly in one line:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['timestamp'],
                                        how='outer'), dfs)
```

Use the `suffixes` argument in the `merge` function to clean up your column headings.